# O365 Graph notifications iCalUId update rollout

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

This is with reference to [Microsoft Graph calendar events – iCalUId Update](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/office/blogs/microsoft-graph-calendar-events-icaluid-update/), And I would like to have an update on whether it has been rolled out to all 365 accounts or Is it underway? If so, please provide the timeline for the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recently I've got a response from Microsoft on this, https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/office/blogs/deferred-icaluid-update-on-ms-graph/?_cache_bypass=1586319170.

In addition to details on the link, they also mentioned followings:

- MSFT has put iCalUid change on hold and doesn't have any plans to change it in the near future,
- they are introducing new fields to identify occurrences in a series of master events. These fields will be supplementary to existing properties while iCalUId continue to exist as it is.

I hope that this will be helpful for someone else who's looking within this regard.